# estimate time for find command

Tags: find

I am trying to find some file in my Linux machine using

```
find . -type f -iname *.locked > /tmp/output.txt &
```

and storing them in to the `output.txt` file.

but the thing I want to know is how much time it will take.

It has been running for a long time.

Comment: It depends on how many directories/files are under the current directory, how fast the file systems are (e.g. network shares will generally be slower), and how busy the system is. Not possible to get an estimate before running the command.

Comment: Be aware that if you have a file `foo.locked` in the working directory, that `find` command will only search for `foo.locked`.